# Simple USB Bootloader

Tags: assembly, usb, bootloader

I'm trying to make a simple bootloader that will run from a USB. After several problems, I tried using the following asm code block (that i got from [MikeOS](http://mikeos.sourceforge.net/write-your-own-os.html)):

```
BITS 16

start:
mov ax, 07C0h       ; Set up 4K stack space after this bootloader
add ax, 288     ; (4096 + 512) / 16 bytes per paragraph
mov ss, ax
mov sp, 4096

mov ax, 07C0h       ; Set data segment to where we're loaded
mov ds, ax

mov si, msg
call move

jmp $   

msg db 'Whatever!', 0

move:
mov ah, 0Eh

.print:
lodsb
cmp al,0
je .Done
int 10h
jmp .print

.Done:
ret

times 510-($-$$) db 0   
dw 0xAA55
```

This resulted in L being printed infinite number of times when i tried to boot it from the USB :(
Can anyone let me know what i'm doing wrong.

I'm copying it into Sector 0, using dd.

Edit: This somehow doesn't work on my PC but works on my sisters laptop.
Anyone have any idea why?

Comment: Your code works for me: http://cl.ly/image/2H0E0Z3I0S3y

Comment: Its working perfectly whenever i try to run it from QEmu or Virtual Box but the problem arises when i restart the PC the boot it directly from the USB

Answer (score 1):

There's no bug in the code you've posted that would explain the symptoms.

*Note: There are 2 bugs. It assumes the direction flag is clear and doesn't do a `cld` before the `lodsb`, but that might cause it to display 'W' followed by strange characters (and not an 'L' repeated). It also doesn't set a value in `bh` for the page number used by "int 0x10, ah=0x0E", but that might cause nothing to be displayed (and not an 'L' repeated).*

Given the absence of a cause in the code itself; the most likely problem is either a problem with how you copy the resulting binary onto the USB flash (more likely), or a problem with how you assemble the code (less likely).

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
I'm using 
dd if=Simple.bin of=/dev/sdc bs=512 count=1
I'm pretty sure i'm copying it correctly cause i checked it in the hex editor and it shows the file at Sector 0

I made the modifications to fix the bugs and now it results in nothing being displayed with cursor on second line and blinking
(i might be doing  the modifications wrong but again, it works fine in virtual manager and causes problem on booting)

Comment: @IrLearn: For "displaying nothing", maybe setting `bh` before using "int 0x10, ah=0x0E" might help.. ;-)